# How to share OneDrive files using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, graph, sharepoint-online, onedrive

I'd like to find an automatic way to share OneDrive files with a specific internal user, what's the best approach?  My current scripts are using PowerShell, but that's not a hard requirement.

I've tried:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0 - what's the best library to use for this?  I've created an AzureAD app with the appropriate delegated permissions.  In PowerShell, once I run Connect-MgGraph, what method can I run to call this?
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitempermission?view=sharepoint-ps - but my OneDrive items aren't part of a list.  Could they be?  The folder permission works well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpfolderpermission but I don't understand why there isn't a file one just like this folder one

I know the absolute URL of the file, the UPN of the internal user I want to directly share with, and I have owner permissions to the file.  How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note this question is too open ended and you're asking way too many questions at once. It might be better to ask new questions focusing on your questions individually, along with code you're attempting to use to solve your problem.